# rails:how to verify what kind of user log in?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm a freshman in programming .This is my solution,but it can't log in.Always show 'Invalid email/password combination'.How to mend my code?And if there are some good web to learn rails ? 
Thanks

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
  <h1>Sign in</h1>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="span6 offset3">
         <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>
           <%= f.label :email %>
           <%= f.text_field :email %>
           <%= f.label :password %>
           <%= f.password_field :password %>
            <%= f.label :type %>
            <%= f.radio_button :type, 1, :checked => true %> Student
            <%= f.radio_button :type, 2 %> Teacher
            <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
          <% end %>
          <p>New students? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Session Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    if [:type] == 1
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        redirect_to user
        #sign_in user
        # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
      else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
        render 'new'
      end
    else 
      teacher = Teacher.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        redirect_to teacher
        #sign_in user
        # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
      else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
        render 'new'
      end
    end 
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      flash[:notice] = "Please sign in"
      redirect_to signin_url
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a value is submitted from a form your controller will receive it in the `params` hash as a string. You aren't calling the params hash. You are also testing against an integer so `[:type] == 1` is always returning false because you need to check `params[:type]` which will have a value of `"1"` or `"2"`.

There are lots of rails tutorials out there but a good place to start is the official guides at [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org)

Comment: Should I use if params[:type] == "1"?